# Microsoft Word for Mac - crazy keyboard response in review comments

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

**Problem**:

I am reviewing a Word document using tracked changes and inserted comments. 
Halfway through the process, I can no longer type normally in the inserted comments. Each time I hit a specific key, what shows up is a corrupted text with multiple repeated letters, all of the repeated letters changing with an additional press on the keyboard. Pressing backspace generates no response.

**Observations**:

- ONLY this specific document that is affected. If I open a new document, all the comment typing functions work perfectly.
- Tends to happen on files with large volumes of tracked changes and comments. It's as if I reach a certain volume of comments, and then BAM! No more commenting.

**Solutions tried and failed**:

- Saving and restarting Microsoft Word
- Restarting laptop

**What I'm using**:

- Microsoft Word for Mac (2011, v.14.1.0)
- 2013 Macbook Air (MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6)
- Laptop built-in keyboard

Thank you in advance for any ideas or suggestions!

Comment: While experiencing the issue in Word, do other apps behave normally?